# Why does padding affect positioning of adjacent element?

Tags: css

On [this code sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bJZoWo),

When I delete the padding on the element with an id of #a, the blue element moves up, and vice versa.

But when I inspect the margins and padding in the Chrome dev tools, it looks like they shouldn't affect each other at all!

Why is the padding of the red element affecting the **VERTICAL** positioning of the blue element?

I understand why it would affect the horizontal, but the vertical change confuses me!

I've looked into the CSS box model, but it hasn't helped.

```css
* {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#a {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 30px;
}

#b {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  CONTENT
</div>

<div id='b'>
  CONTENT
</div>
```

I expect that changing the padding of the red el wouldn't affect the positioning of the blue el at all!

Comment: TL;DR from the duplicates: "baseline default vertical alignement"

Comment: `inline-block` is affected by `vertical-align`. Can add `float: left` to the element, or modify `vertical-align: top` (for example) to change this behavior.